# From one File to Multiple Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to write a Python script which takes a special type of file as input.
This file contains information about multiple genes, and the information about one gene is written over multiple lines, where the number of lines is not the same for every gene. An example would be:

```
 gene            join(373616..374161,1..174)
                 /locus_tag="AM1_A0001"
                 /db_xref="GeneID:5685236"
 CDS             join(373616..374161,1..174)
                 /locus_tag="AM1_A0001"
                 /codon_start=1
                 /transl_table=11
                 /product="glutathione S-transferase, putative"
                 /protein_id="YP_001520660.1"
                 /db_xref="GI:158339653"
                 /db_xref="GeneID:5685236"
                 /translation="MKIVSFKICPFVQRVTALLEAKGIDYDIEYIDLSHKPQWFLDLS
                 PNAQVPILITDDDDVLFESDAIVEFLDEVVGTPLSSDNAVKKAQDRAWSYLATKHYLV
                 QCSAQRSPDAKTLEERSKKLSKAFGKIKVQLGESRYINGDDLSMVDIAWLPLLHRAAI
                 IEQYSGYDFLEEFPKVKQWQQHLLSTGIAEKSVPEDFEERFTAFYLAESTCLGQLAKS
                 KNGEACCGTAECTVDDLGCCA"
 gene            241..381
                 /locus_tag="AM1_A0002"
                 /db_xref="GeneID:5685411"
 CDS             241..381
                 /locus_tag="AM1_A0002"
                 /codon_start=1
                 /transl_table=11
                 /product="hypothetical protein"
                 /protein_id="YP_001520661.1"
                 /db_xref="GI:158339654"
                 /db_xref="GeneID:5685411"
                 /translation="MLINPEDKQVEIYRPGQDVELLQSPSTISGADVLPEFSLNLEWI
                 WR"
 gene            388..525
                 /locus_tag="AM1_A0003"
                 /db_xref="GeneID:5685412"
 CDS             388..525
                 /locus_tag="AM1_A0003"
                 /codon_start=1
                 /transl_table=11
                 /product="hypothetical protein"
                 /protein_id="YP_001520662.1"
                 /db_xref="GI:158339655"
                 /db_xref="GeneID:5685412"
                 /translation="MKEAGFSENSRSREGQPKLAKDAAIAKPYLVAMTAELQIMATET
                 L"
```

What I want, now, is to create a list of dictionaries, where every dictionary contains the information about one gene, like this:

```
gene_1 = {"locus": /locus_tag, "product": /product, ...}
gene_2 = {"locus": /locus_tag, "product": /product, ...}
```

I have absolutely no idea how I could make Python know when one gene/dictionary is finished and the next should start.
Can someone please help me? Is there a way to do this?

For clarification: I know how to extract the information I want, save it in variables and get it into the dictionary. I just don't know how to tell Python to create one dictionary per gene.

Comment: have you put *any* code together as an attempt to solve this? If so, do post it.

Comment: Can a colon appear as part of a value? If not, you could simply find the start of a new entity by checking if the line contains a colon...

Comment: @PaulC I tried simply looping through the file, but that won't do it. I've been searching for new ideas for days, but I seem to be too much of a beginner to come up with something. Extracting the data and filling the dictionaries is not a problem, just that simple looping won't do.

Comment: @l4mpi I'm afraid there will be other colons as well.

Comment: Does the word 'Person' appears at every start of a new entity?

Comment: @andrean Yes, I was thinking about using that, but I'm not sure how...

Comment: how does one know if the current information under one entity is age or height or something else?

Comment: If you're going to give a sample data file, give real sample data. The expected output is a dict that uses variables. Where is the spec for this "special type of file"? What's generating it? Why aren't you using JSON, XML, YAML, or something along those lines?

Comment: @Wooble There you are. And I don't know any of the languages you suggested, so I can't use them.

Comment: Well, the format you're using is at least actually structured, unlike your original example. On the other hand, it's also very complex. You may want to look at the `pyparsing` module. Note that you almost certainly don't actually want one `dict` per gene, but rather a list of dicts or a dict of dicts; having an arbitrary number of dynamically-named variables is something a lot of people think they want and they're nearly always wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Wooble I will have a look at this. :-)
Yes, I want a list of dicts.

Comment: if "gene" always indicates the start of a gene have you tried using new_list = data_as_a_string.split('gene') then upon every occurrence of gene you will get a entry in a list containing the data between each "gene" occurrence.

Comment: @PaulC Awwesome! That does the trick and is so clean and simple. Thank you so very much!

Comment: Glad to help the cause of science, even just a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is interested in the beginner's solution I found with the help of the comments I received, here it is:

```
import sys, re

annot = file("example.embl", "r")
embl = ""
annotation = []

for line in annot:
    embl += line

embl_list = embl.split("FT   gen")

for item in embl_list:
    if "e            " in item:
        split_item = item.split("\n")
        for l in split_item:
            if "e            " in l:
                if not "complement" in l:
                    coordinates = l[13:len(l)]
                    C = coordinates.split("..")
                    genestart = C[0]
                    geneend = C[1]
                    strand = "+"
                if "complement" in l:
                    coordinates = l[24:len(l)-1]
                    C = coordinates.split("..")
                    genestart = C[0]
                    geneend = C[1]
                    strand = "-"

            if "/locus_tag" in l:
                L = l.split('"')
                locus = L[1]

            if "/product" in l:
                P = l.split('"')
                product = P[1]

        annotation.append({
            "locus": locus,
            "genestart": genestart,
            "geneend": geneend,
            "product": product,
        })
    else:
        print "Finished!"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've put together a maybe not too nice, but functional parser for this, pure python, maybe it can be used at least as a basic idea:

```
import re
import pprint
printer = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

with open("entities.txt", "r") as file_obj:
    entities = list()

    for line in file_obj.readlines():
        line = line.replace('\n', '')

        if re.match(r'\s*(gene|CDS)\s+[\w(\.,)]+', line):
            parts = line.split()
            entity = {parts[0]: parts[1]}
            entities.append(entity)
        else:
            try:
                (attr_name,) = re.findall(r'/\w+=', line)
                attr_name = attr_name.strip('/=')
            except ValueError:
                addition = line.strip()
                entity[last_key] = ''.join([entity[last_key], addition])
            else:
                try:
                    (attr_value,) = re.findall(r'="\w+$', line)
                    last_key = attr_name
                except ValueError:
                    try:
                        (attr_value,) = re.findall(r'="[\w\s\.:,-]+"', line)
                    except ValueError:
                        (attr_value,) = re.findall(r'=\d+$', line)

                    attr_value = attr_value.strip('"=')

                if attr_name in entity:
                    entity[attr_name] = [entity[attr_name], attr_value]
                else:
                    entity[attr_name] = attr_value

printer.pprint(entities)
```

Comment: Thanks, andrean!
I already have a working solution now, thanks to Paul C's tip, but your's looks much more clean.